# Prove $a_i(x)=b_i(x) , \forall i=1,2\cdots$ such that $y_1,\cdots ,y_n$ are independent.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$a_i,b_i, i=1,2\cdots$ are continuous functions.

Suppose $$y^{(n)}+a_1(x)y^{(n-1)}+\cdots+a_n(x)y=0$$ $$y^{(n)}+b_1(x)y^{(n-1)}+\cdots+b_n(x)y=0$$

such that $y_1,\cdots ,y_n$ are common independent solutions for both equations.

Prove $a_i(x)=b_i(x) , \forall i=1,2\cdots$

My solution:

Suppose $\exists i$ such that $a_i(x)\neq b_i(x)$.

$$W[y_1,\cdots,y_n](\vec a)=\vec 0$$ $$W[y_1,\cdots,y_n](\vec b)=\vec 0$$.

$\vec a , \vec b$ are both solutions of the homogenues system equation , than the rank of $W[y_1,\cdots,y_n] <n \implies y_1,\cdots ,y_n$ are not independent.

Contradicition.

Then , $a_i(x)=b_i(x)$.

Is my solution correct ?

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the functions $y^{(n)}$ are independent. If I understand correctly then the definition you are using in the proof you give means the statement is vacuously true, i.e. nothing can ever satify the conditions you ask for. If instead you want the $y^{(n)}$ to be independent over $\mathbb{R}$ then your proof doesn't seem valid to me.

Comment: Do you mean transforming the nth order DE into a first order system (i.e. $y_1=y, y_2=y_1',...$, etc.)?

Comment: Additionally you refer to $y_n$ and $y^{(n)}$. Are these meant to be the same? If they are what do you mean when you refer to $y_1$ does it mean $y$ or $y^{(1)}$. Sorry for asking lots of questions, it just isn't really clear what you are asking about.

Comment: $y^{(n)}$ is the n-derivation of y , while $y_n$ is the n-th solution of the equation.

Comment: What is $W[y_1,...,y_n](\vec a)$? The matrix of function values and derivatives and its determinant do not contain any references to the coefficients.

Comment: @erez I would reccomend that you make it clearer that this is what you mean. For example by indexing the derivatives by $k$ or anything other than $n$ and also adding subscripts to the $y$ in the 2 equations.

Comment: @erez In summary you are asking if 2 linear differential equations with leading coefficient 1 have the same set of solutions are they the same.

Comment: @Fishbane Exactly!

Comment: @erez Apologies for not saying anything for a while, I have been rather busy. In short, if 2 linear differential equations with leading coefficient 1 have the same set of solutions then to my knowledge they are indeed the same. The exact method you use to prove it doesn't seem to be valid however. Instead I would suggest that you subtract the two equations and conclude that you have n solutions to a linear differential equation of order n-1 which is a contradiction.